# How to know when process finishes always?

Tags: java, process, wait, notify

I am doing a program in which I have to wait a process to finish to continue their execution. I made the next:

```
synchronized (obj) {
   try{
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   p.waitFor();
   obj.notifyAll();
   System.out.println("The program command has finished");
   ...
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

where:

**command** is an string which contains the process command to execute

**obj** is is an object of the class object

I realized that sometimes the sentence *"The program command has finished"* is not written. It sometimes is solved changing the call to *notifyAll* to *notify* and viceversa. My question is: which is the best way to do this without problems like this?

Comment: [`Process#waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

Answer (score 1):

I see two immediate ways to improve your program:

1. do not use the obsolete wait/notify mechanism. Instead rely on concurrency helpers in `java.util.concurrent`. Depending on the wider picture, `CountDownLatch`, `Semaphore`, or `Phaser` may be the best choice;
2. it is dangerous to let the subprocess run without consuming its output streams, it may easily lead to a deadlock on `waitFor()`. Use `ProcessBuilder` with `inheritIO` to avoid that.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I'm a little bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I discover my problem: the problem was the the output buffer of the external program was full and this was the cause because the process was locked. I had to read all the output of the program before the waitfor and my problem was solved.